# URL Helper - undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

rake routes:

```
api_v1_accounts GET    /api/v1/accounts(.:format)      {:action=>"index", :controller=>"api/v1/accounts"}
```

That means I should have a url helper method:

```
api_v1_accounts_url
```

I am trying to test creating an account with rspec and the following line fails:

```
route = api_v1_accounts_url(account)
```

Saying that `api_v1_accounts_url` is an undefined method

I guess I've really misunderstood something about URL helper methods and the scope of them. Please help

Comment: I am noticing that you are passing an argument to api_v1_accounts_url(account), which does not accept one.

Comment: @Gerry - still undefined

Comment: @Gerry - Looks like it should accept an argument, works in my view. Just not in my test.

Comment: Is it a problem of scope? Something I have to include for it to work?

Comment: What Rails version are you using/

Comment: Ok I guess you are looking for something like including the routing url helpers. Just put this in your test include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

Answer (score 2):

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

That did the trick